# Отмена git rebase -i

Tags: git, gitlab, git-rebase

Было у меня 2 комита "Добавлены новые исключения" и "Сменил описание в ReleaseNotes",
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решил их объединить. Они объединились под именем "Добавлены новые исключения". Но в результате мое изменение объединилось, с комитом другого человека
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как то можно отменить полностью все операции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменения не объединились. `git rebase -i` меняет идентификаторы комитов, которые находятся в истории после точки, где вы ее изменили (выбрали fixup в данном случае). Поэтому комит от другого человека получил новый идентификатор, хотя по содержимому остался таким же.

Вернуть все можно пока старые комиты все еще есть в git reflog (до следующей сборки мусора). Нужно всего лишь переставить указатель бранча branch255 на комит, который был последним в бранче branch255 до того как вы начали rebase. Любые операции с репозиторием (кроме очистки мусора), не удаляют старые комиты, а создают новые. Старые комиты остаются в репозитории (они стают недоступны через указатели веток, но их видно в `git reflog`), они доступны для любых действий и можно к ним вернуться, например, создав новый бранч указывающий на такой комт.

В любом случае рекомендую перед экспериментами сделать запасную копию репозитория, чтоб можно было откатить если что. Вы в вопросе вставили картинку, поэтому в номерах комитов тут могут быть опечатки.

Комит который вас интересует, судя по всему, это последний комит перед `HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2`, т.е. `3e91394844`. Проверьте так ли это. Для этого выполните команду `git log 3e91394844`. Если она показывает правильную историю комитов, т.е. то что вы хотите получить, то нужно именно на этот комит переставить бранч `branch255` (если нет то поищите среди комитов в reflog тот что вам нужно проверяя историю с помощью `git log <id комита>` чтоб найти нужную точку).

Если `branch255` у вас текущий, то перенаправить бранч можно командой (внимание, если вы делали комиты после rebase в этот бранч, то чтобы их не потерять, рекомендую создать вначале новый временный бранч от последнего комита в `branch255):

```
git reset --hard 3e91394844
```

Если же вы находитесь на другом бранче, то чтобы переставить `branch255` воспользуйтесь командой:

```
git branch -f branch255 3e91394844
```